# Cant use Nodejs npm "/c: /c: Is a directory" error

Tags: node.js, npm

If I try to use "npm" in any cases i get

```
/c: /c: Is a directory
```

I reinstalled node.js but it didnt fixed the problem. Any idea where i can find this and fix it?

Comment: how and from where are you running `npm`?

Comment: Doesnt matter, i can run it from android studio, i can run it from git bash or from cmd and i always get the same error.

Comment: Check your system path variable, make sure that nodejs is added in there properly. But the output message seems to suggest that the actual input is just `/c` in a bash based console. However, cmd is not bash based, so I'm confused even more now. If you uninstall node, does it still do that or do you get a "npm not found" type of message?

Comment: Alright i checked it again with cmd. If i use it there it works. So if i uninstall node i get the "npm not found" type of message yes. I checked the system variables and there should be everything fine. nodejs added and also Comspec on cmd

Comment: okay so it actually works in the cmd console, but not in other situations. Have you restarted your computer and/or the consoles since the installation? Unfortunately otherwise I'm at a loss, so all I can do is wish you good luck now. (But at least you have a somewhat functional solution, just gotta use it with cmd)